# Django template variable in an input value

Tags: html, django

I'm trying to put a django template variable inside an input value like this:

```
First name: <input name="fname"  type="text" value="{{ patient.firstName }}"><br>
```

This is not working, nothing is printed. Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Can you access `patient` in your template at all?

Comment: Hi Henrik. It worked finally, No idea why ! Thank you !